# Number of active users in GA4 appears different in Reports and Acquisitions menu

Tags: google-analytics-4

I want to count monthly active users for my web service. Since the web service has multiple domains, the GA needs to apply a filter.

Explore report was also set under the same conditions as the acquisition menu, but the numbers are slightly different. The total count appears to count unique users in the Acquisition menu, but appears as a simple sum in Explore menu.

Which one should I believe? Why is there a difference between the two?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZF7C.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH7LU.png)